# Creating a dictionary from default dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionary.

```
new_entries = []
new_entries.append({'id':1,'a':1,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':2,'a':3,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':3,'a':4,'b':3})
new_entries.append({'id':4,'a':5,'b':6})
new_entries.append({'id':5,'a':8,'b':9})
new_entries.append({'id':6,'a':9,'b':8})
new_entries.append({'id':7,'a':1,'b':4})
new_entries.append({'id':8,'a':1,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':9,'a':3,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':10,'a':6,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':11,'a':6,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':12,'a':6,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':13,'a':7,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':14,'a':7,'b':2})
new_entries.append({'id':15,'a':7,'b':2})
```

And I want duplicate ids based on a and b keys. Means id 1 and id 9 are same as their a,b are the same. Similarly 10,11,12 too.
So, I want a dictionary out of it which has the following structure

```
1:set([8])
8:set([1])
10:set([11,12])
11:set([10,12])
12:set([10,11])
```

I wrote the following code for that

```
dummy_store = {}
dedup_store = defaultdict(set)

for entry in new_entries:
    if (entry['a'],entry['b']) in dummy_store:
        dedup_store[dummy_store[(entry['a'],entry['b'])]].add(entry['id'])
        continue
    dummy_store[(entry['a'],entry['b'])] = entry['id']
```

After that, I am able to get the one end of association so, my dedup_store dictionary contains
1:set([8])
10:set([11,12])

But the other entries in the dict, I am unable to get.
I need

```
8:set([1])
11:set([10,12])
12:set([10,11])
```

as well. How to get that done??

Answer (score 0):

Keys get overriten in dummy_store

Something like this should work:

```
new_entries = [
    {'id': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 2, 'a': 3, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 3, 'a': 4, 'b': 3},
    {'id': 4, 'a': 5, 'b': 6},
    {'id': 5, 'a': 8, 'b': 9},
    {'id': 6, 'a': 9, 'b': 8},
    {'id': 7, 'a': 1, 'b': 4},
    {'id': 8, 'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 9, 'a': 3, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 10, 'a': 6, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 11, 'a': 6, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 12, 'a': 6, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 13, 'a': 7, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 14, 'a': 7, 'b': 2},
    {'id': 15, 'a': 7, 'b': 2},
]

data = {entry['id']: (entry['a'], entry['b']) for entry in new_entries}

temp = defaultdict(set)
dedup_store = defaultdict(set)

for k, v in data.items():
    temp[v].add(k)

for ids in temp.values():
    for id in ids:
        dedup_store[id] = ids.difference({id})
```

---

```
In [99]: dict(dedup_store)
Out[99]: 
{1: {8},
 2: {9},
 3: set(),
 4: set(),
 5: set(),
 6: set(),
 7: set(),
 8: {1},
 9: {2},
 10: {11, 12},
 11: {10, 12},
 12: {10, 11},
 13: {14, 15},
 14: {13, 15},
 15: {13, 14}}
```

ok ->

```
defaultdict(set, filter(lambda x: x[1], reduce(lambda r, e: r.__setitem__(e['id'], {_e['id'] for _e in new_entries if _e['a'] == e['a'] and _e['b'] == e['b'] and e['id'] != _e['id']}) or r, new_entries, {}).iteritems()))
```

Comment: I do not want keys with empty set. Would really appreciate if temp dict is not used!!

Answer (score 0):

Not very pythonish, but you can first store each duplicate entry in a dictionary and then iterate over the dictionary to produce the output you want

```
items = {}

for item in new_entries:
    key = str(item["a"]) + "-" + str(item["b"])
    if items.has_key(key):
        items[key].append(item["id"])
    else:
        items[key] = [item["id"]]


for item in items:
    if len(items[item]) > 1:
        for idx, val in enumerate(items[item]):
            print str(val) + ":set(" + str(items[item][idx + 1:] + (items[item][:idx])) + ")"
```